# Excel Userform Mousemove event to change TextboxValue

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a textbox control (Textbox1) and a label control lbl1.
I have setup an x and y to capture the location of the control and then I use the mousemove/mouse down events to move the lbl1 control. The problem with this is I want the textbox1.value to change from 0 to 100 based on the mousemove x, so as I drag along the values in Textbox1 should increase from 0 to 100 as they would on a webpage slider. Is this possible?

```
'VBA script
Dim myX As Double
Dim myY As Double


Private Sub lbl1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    myX= X
    myY= Y
 
End Sub

Private Sub Lbl1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
 

    If Button And 1 Then
    
     lbl1.Left = lbl1.Left + (X - myX)

    End If
        If lbl1.Left < 6 Then
            lbl1.Left = 6
        ElseIf lbl1.Left > 126 Then
                lbl1.Left = 126
               
        End If
end sub
```

I have tried to use textbox1.value = lbl1.left -6 but this does not work and not sure of the calculation or if this is the correct way to change this value.

Comment: What *actually happens* when you try this?  "does not work" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I will make sure the next time i ask to include this detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a little bit of math to scale that 6-126 to 0-100:

```vb
Dim myX As Double
Dim myY As Double


Private Sub lbl1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    myX = X
    myY = Y
End Sub

Private Sub Lbl1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Const MIN_LEFT As Long = 6
    Const MAX_SPAN As Long = 120
    Dim newpos As Long, maxLeft As Long
    
    If Button And 1 Then
        maxLeft = MIN_LEFT + MAX_SPAN
        newpos = lbl1.Left + (X - myX)
        If newpos < MIN_LEFT Then newpos = MIN_LEFT
        If newpos > maxLeft Then newpos = maxLeft
        lbl1.Left = newpos
        TextBox1.Text = 100 * (newpos - MIN_LEFT) / MAX_SPAN  'scale 6-126 value to 0-100
    End If
End Sub
```